# Background (rounded corners) of a recycler view does not appear without adding some padding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-drawable

I have the following drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>  
    <corners android:radius="6dp"/>  
</shape>
```

Adding that to a recyclerview using `android:background="@drawable/my_bg_drawable"` does not seem to work.
I included a LinearLayout to wrap the recycler view and added the background to the LinearLayout but that had no effect either.
The following worked:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"  
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"  
       android:layout_marginRight="10dp"  
       android:padding="2dp"  
       android:background="@drawable/my_bg_drawable">    
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView  
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
                    />  

       </LinearLayout>
```

Basically adding the padding `android:padding="2dp"` allowed the background to become visible (at least that was when the corners showed up).
Why does this work like this and I have to use padding?

Comment: maybe the recylcer view does take all the space of the linearlayout, but with padding it can´t...can you post some images of before and after to get a better understanding?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs:then why does it not work when the background is in the recyclerview. The difference is that the corners show up squared and with padding the corners show up as rounded (the background has defined them as rounded)

Comment: But put it in the recyclerView can´t work as you are using an item for a recycler view. I guess it would work if you put it into the item layout xml....

Comment: or, if it shouldn´t be shown for every item, more as a background, then I think you have to make your items background transparent....but I think it would be more helpful to see an image of your problem...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs: The only thing I am trying to do is to have a list of items that on the top border of the list and the bottom border of the list the corners are rounded. That's it. That is why I added the background to the recycler view as it is not related to the view coming from the viewholder.